# Use string as PK and FK on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I`m trying to use String as Primary/Foreign key on a small crawler that I'm making. But I keep receiving the following error when I try to use the Associations methods (eg.: a.crawler_details - Where a is an object called Asin):

```
RangeError: 8532503039 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4
```

Record example:

```
#<Asin asin: "8532503039", title: "O Físico", image_url: nil, active: false, created_at: "2015-05-04 03:30:29", updated_at: "2015-05-04 03:30:36">
```

Here are the details:

```
2.1.2 :001 > Asin.new
 => #<Asin asin: nil, title: nil, image_url: nil, active: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

2.1.2 :002 > CrawlerDetail.new
 => #<CrawlerDetail id: nil, amazon_price: nil, feed_price: nil, first_place: nil, second_place: nil, third_place: nil, fp_price: nil, sp_price: nil, tp_price: nil, run: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>


class Asin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :crawler_details, :foreign_key => 'id', :primary_key=> 'asin'

    self.primary_key = 'asin' 
    ...
end


class CrawlerDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :asin, :foreign_key => 'asin', :primary_key => 'id'
end
```

I also tried the belongs_to relation but with no luck. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not association error , did you defined **field name "asin" type integer** in your database table ?

it may help please try to alter your database table from type integer to string .